# Returning first values, then all the other values, in two separate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the first or primary coordinator from a list of coordinator names. However, I also need to save all other coordinators listed. As you can guess, the list of coordinator names has duplicates:

```
      Tags                   Name
0     333000                 Lala
1     333000                Dipsy
2     333000                  Poe
3     111111          Tinky Winky
```

Therefore, in my own dataframe I would like to return:

```
       Tags                Primary                              Others
0    333000                   Lala                          Dipsy, Poe
1    111111            Tinky Winky                                 NaN
```

While I am able to return Primary fine with this code:

```py
df['Primary'] = df.join(coordinator_df.groupby(['Tags']).nth(0)['Name'], on='Tags)['Name']
```

my attempt for Others returns an error:

```
df['Primary'] = df.join(coordinator_df.groupby(['Tags']).nth([0, 1, 2])['Name'], on='Tags)['Name']
```

Error:
`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

I would appreciate help either with this specific error, or any other approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def Others(x):
    return ', '.join(x.iloc[1:])

df.groupby('Tags')['Name'].agg({'first', Others})
```

Output:

```
            Others        first
Tags                           
111111              Tinky Winky
333000  Dipsy, Poe         Lala
```

Where instead of `NaN`, you have the empty string.

Comment: in pandas 0.25.0, `df.groupby('Tags')['Name'].agg(First='first',Others=lambda x: ','.join(x.iloc[1:]))`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reference where I can see a list of potential "smart" arguments to pass into .agg (eg. other arguments like 'first'?)

Comment: @ChristinaZhou The [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html)?

Comment: Thanks! (Didn't realize it counted as a computation)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to store all values in a list after grouping, and then just splitting that list column up into 2 new variables.

```py
import numpy as np
df = df.groupby(['Tags']).agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()

df['Primary'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['Others'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[1:] if len(x) > 1 else np.nan)
```